# NSDictionary structure not getting done properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

i want to make a structure like following using NSDictionary

```
{
 "request":
    {
      "email":"manger@abc.com",
      "password":"manager"
    }
}
```

I'm using the following code in objective C

```
  NSDictionary *paramsDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"manger@hall.com",@"email",
                           @"manager",@"password",
                           nil];


  NSDictionary *req = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           paramsDic,@"request",
                           nil];
```

but it returns the following response

```
 {
   request =     
   {
      email = "manger@abc.com";
      password = manager;
   };
 }
```

it shows semicolons instead of commas , one extra semicolon and keys are not in inverted commas

Comment: Your *structure* is JSON, you need `NSJSONSerialization`. There are thousands of related questions here on SO

Comment: You are calling `-description` method of `NSDictionary`, that's how iOS prints a dictionary. Nothing wrong about it. Now, your dictionary is JSON Valid, you need to use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert it to `NSData`, you can convert then the `NSData` to `NSString` if you want.

Comment: thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert req to JSON object

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:req options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonData);
```